# To develop a command line interface where a text or XML file can be sent to a JIRA to execute multiple individual/unique tasks

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

**strong text**
i could not get how i can perform unique individual tasks like...

Example:

50 issues to link with 50 different issues ,

i have entered the ISSUE number ,lintk type and the target issue number in an excel sheet.

now i need to perform action of linking the issues with its target as mentioned in the excel sheet through COMMAND LINE.

Could you please help me in this regard.

We Dont have Jira Command line interface plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

If JIRA CLI does this, then I'd install that. Otherwise you could try using jira-python and the create_issue_link method. This assumes that your JIRA version is 5.x or later.
 http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: i need to do this in JAVA and can one help me in writing a simple program to interact with JIRA through Command Line.